# Is Xdebug supported for php7.1.1?

Tags: web-development

I am searching in Google **Xdebug for php7.1.1** but there is nothing that can really answer my question, though I found this https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/444, but the version is php7.1.0, so I can't fully rely on this answer.

I followed the instructions given here, https://xdebug.org/wizard.php, and then I received a problem, `phpize` that I installed (from the instruction https://xdebug.org/docs/faq#phpize) is not compatible to php version (php7.1.1), then tried to resolve it by from the instruction https://xdebug.org/docs/faq#custom-phpize, still not working.

Is there any workaround here?

*If my question is not suitable to this site, please do tell me.*

**Update**

Here is the result of `phpize`:

```
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20151012
Zend Module Api No:      20151012
Zend Extension Api No:   320151012
```

Instead of:

```
Configuring for:
...
Zend Module Api No:      20160303
Zend Extension Api No:   320160303
```

given in the instructions here https://xdebug.org/wizard.php.

Answer (score 2):

Xdebug 2.5.x supports PHP 7.0.x and PHP 7.1.x, as well as PHP's master branch, as per https://xdebug.org/#2016_12_04:

```
PHP 7.1.3-dev (cli) (built: Feb 16 2017 11:18:14) ( NTS DEBUG )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.6.0-dev, Copyright (c) 2002-2017, by Derick Rethans
```

Comment: no `PHP 7.1.x` said in https://xdebug.org/#2016_12_04

Comment: @DumbQuestion I love that you're disagreeing with the guy who literally wrote Xdebug.

Comment: oh I did not know, sorry if I am being disrespectful, but I really did not see it though, I have a problem with the `phpize` xdebug recommended to me to install, `phpize` reading my php version as `7.0` instead of `7.1.1`, here is the result, `Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20151012
Zend Module Api No:      20151012
Zend Extension Api No:   320151012`

Answer (score 1):

Now. supprot php 7.1, do not support 7.1.1
See here please

[2016-12-04] - Xdebug 2.5.0 is out!
This is the first released to support PHP 7.1.

Besides support for PHP 7.1, it also adds support for IPv6. A few bugs have been fixed as well.

The full change log can be found on the updates page. The source code can be found on the downloads page, and as usual, Xdebug is installable through PECL.

Comment: what link are you referring to?